# Chrome Extension dom element to image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I trying to develop my first chrome extension to convert a DOM element into an image.

I looked at example extensions to try and understand how to achieve this, and there are some very good example for creating an image from the whole page, but not for a specific element.

I also looked and some javascript libraries that save a canvas to image (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

So far I have created the basic setup with a popup and a button to trigger the script:

```
function handleDOM (results){
      console.log('ELEMENT:', results)

      html2canvas($(results), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#btn-thumbnail').click(function(){
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
            var tab = tabs[0];
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'document.getElementById("elementId")'
            }, handleDOM);
        });
    })
```

But this doesn't work because I am guessing the html2canvas requires access to the DOM to find the element.

Any suggestions as to how to approach this would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: executeScript transfers results for JSON-ifiable portion of objects only. Meaning, DOM elements can't be transferred. Process the image in a content script.

Comment: In a popup, to get the current tab, you will almost always want to use `chrome.tabs.query({active: true,currentWindow:true}` (i.e. including `currentWindow:true`). Without it, you will be provided a list of active tabs in all windows, which results in the active tab in the current window not being guaranteed to be the first element in the list. If you don't include `currentWindow:true`, you will have an intermittent bug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try injecting a content script that takes the canvas shot?  Content scripts have access to the dom as they're injected into the current page.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts